# Zonal Statistics tool not working with QGIS?

Tags: zonal-statistics, qgis-2.14

I wanted to try the QGIS 2.14 zonal statistic tool but it doesn't work.The system says:

> not a sequence See log for more details

The SAGA Zonal Statistic tool works fine. It also doesn't work with the model builder.

Comment: I think it was reported as a bug [here](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14412)

Comment: @dof1985 I think you should expand upon your comment slightly to make an answer.

Comment: I get the same error in QGGIS 2.18.3

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you update the URL to the bug? QGGIS 2.18.3